# Is it possible to create a multiple color (stacked) bar chart using MPAndroidChart?

Tags: android, bar-chart, mpandroidchart

I have below data to represent in chart format using MPAndroidChart library:

```
Subject Marks       
    Needs Attention Average Outstanding
Hindi    1/5     2/5     2/5
English  2/7     3/7     2/7
Maths    1/3     1/3     1/3
Science  2/7     2/7     3/7
Physics  2/9     4/9     4/9
Sanskrit 3/7     3/5     0
```

And I want a chart like below:

[image: a stacked bar chart]

The above chart is only sample, I want three colours in each bar (stacked). I have already made a bar chart with separate colors, but can't make such multiple coloured chart. Is it possible in MPAndroidChart?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is called a "stacked bar chart" and it is possible in MPAndroidChart.

There is an example Activity in the Github repo for MPAndroidChart [here](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/blob/master/MPChartExample/src/main/java/com/xxmassdeveloper/mpchartexample/StackedBarActivity.java) generated by the following code:

```
    ArrayList<BarEntry> yVals1 = new ArrayList<BarEntry>();

    for (int i = 0; i < size + 1; i++) {
        float mult = (size + 1);
        float val1 = (float) (Math.random() * mult) + mult / 3;
        float val2 = (float) (Math.random() * mult) + mult / 3;
        float val3 = (float) (Math.random() * mult) + mult / 3;

        yVals1.add(new BarEntry(
                i,
                new float[]{val1, val2, val3},
                getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.star)));
    }

    BarDataSet set1;

    if (mChart.getData() != null &&
            mChart.getData().getDataSetCount() > 0) {
        set1 = (BarDataSet) mChart.getData().getDataSetByIndex(0);
        set1.setValues(yVals1);
        mChart.getData().notifyDataChanged();
        mChart.notifyDataSetChanged();
    } else {
        set1 = new BarDataSet(yVals1, "Statistics Vienna 2014");
        set1.setDrawIcons(false);
        set1.setColors(getColors());
        set1.setStackLabels(new String[]{"Births", "Divorces", "Marriages"});

        ArrayList<IBarDataSet> dataSets = new ArrayList<IBarDataSet>();
        dataSets.add(set1);

        BarData data = new BarData(dataSets);
        data.setValueFormatter(new MyValueFormatter());
        data.setValueTextColor(Color.WHITE);

        mChart.setData(data);
    }

    mChart.setFitBars(true);
    mChart.invalidate();
```

And the output looks like this:

[image: stacked bar chart]

Comment: could you describe detail in data.setValueFormatter(new MyValueFormatter()); in detail

Comment: @Teekam it's in the GitHub repo: https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/blob/master/MPChartExample/src/com/xxmassdeveloper/mpchartexample/custom/MyValueFormatter.java

Comment: HI Daviid got solution,thanks. One more think in my chart, bar value is shown on top of each bar and I want it will be shown as mpandroid chart example chart.

Comment: @Teekam try : `mChart.setDrawValueAboveBar(false); mChart.setHighlightFullBarEnabled(false);`

Comment: Updated: https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/blob/master/MPChartExample/src/main/java/com/xxmassdeveloper/mpchartexample/custom/MyValueFormatter.java

Comment: Is there a way to get the bar curved at the top ?

Answer (score 1):

according to me, you can set that logically in mpchart library

else

you can use [achartengine](https://github.com/ddanny/achartengine)

[image]

Comment: Thanks you for consideration, Given chart is good one but I want as in stacked bar chart