# Android BarChart (grouped DataSets) set Bars On Each Other

Tags: android, charts, bar-chart, mpandroidchart

i want a BarChart (grouped DataSets) with special option :

i am creating an android app from an old window app wich has this special chart !

[ScreenShot From Old Software Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zuxAa.jpg)

is there any android library to create this type of bar chart ?

I tried

https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart and android-graphview.org/

Thank You

Comment: there are many but this(you have used) is better

Comment: Try this one , its good https://github.com/Androguide/HoloGraphLibrary

Comment: @AbdulKawee  I saw The Samples No One Has Two Bar On top of each other like the screenshot i shared

Comment: Point is no library will give exactly what you want , you have to do little modifications for what you want.

Comment: Hi Jasone. Have you seen [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/43540294/5241933) about stacked bar charts? I think you may need something like that.

Comment: @DavidRawson tnx , that is great !

Comment: @jasone I'm glad it helped. Do you want to close this question as a duplicate of the one about stacked bar charts? It will still be available for other users to search but will be linked to the older question

Comment: @DavidRawson sure , but i cant find the close button !

Comment: @jasone it should be there now