# MPAndroidChart Make 0-100 percent StackBarGraph with values adjusted in stackbar

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

**Desired StackBar Output:**
[image: Desired StackBar Output]

This is what I want to achieve with values getting adjusted automatically within 0-100 percent range

**Current Stackbar**

[image: Current Stackbar]

Stackbars crossing 100 % range and values are not adjusted

```
leftAxis.setAxisMinimum(0f);

leftAxis.setAxisMaximum(100f);
```

These 2 properties allow me to set the range on Y axis but it's crossing 100 percent threshold

```
    mChart.getDescription().setEnabled(false);
    mChart.setMaxVisibleValueCount(40);
    mChart.setPinchZoom(false);
    mChart.setDrawGridBackground(false);
    mChart.setDrawBarShadow(false);
    mChart.setDrawValueAboveBar(false);
    mChart.setHighlightFullBarEnabled(false);
    mChart.setDoubleTapToZoomEnabled(false);
    mChart.getAxisRight().setEnabled(false);

    XAxis xAxis = mChart.getXAxis();
    xAxis.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);
    xAxis.setTypeface(mTfLight);
    xAxis.setDrawGridLines(false);
    xAxis.setGranularity(1f); // only intervals of 1 day
    xAxis.setLabelCount(13);
```

//        xAxis.setValueFormatter(xAxisFormatter);

```
    IAxisValueFormatter custom = new MyAxisValueFormatter();

    YAxis leftAxis = mChart.getAxisLeft();
    leftAxis.setTypeface(mTfLight);
    leftAxis.setLabelCount(2, false);
    leftAxis.setValueFormatter(custom);
    leftAxis.setPosition(YAxis.YAxisLabelPosition.OUTSIDE_CHART);
    leftAxis.setSpaceTop(15f);
    leftAxis.setAxisMinimum(0f); // this replaces setStartAtZero(true)
    leftAxis.setAxisMaximum(100f);
    mChart.getAxisRight().setEnabled(false);
```

Rest of the code

Comment: I think you are mixing BarChart & StackBarGraph together

Comment: @VVB yes I'm using BarDataSet to populate my stacked bars.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43540294/is-it-possible-to-create-a-multiple-color-stacked-bar-chart-using-mpandroidcha?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: @VVB I have built stacks using same link..I want percentage stacked bar like in this example https://www.numetriclabz.com/android-percentage-stacked-column-chart-using-numandroidcharts-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

**I got a workaround for this**

```
        float rand1 = (float) (Math.random() * mult) + mult / 3;
        float rand2 = (float) (Math.random() * mult) + mult / 3;
        float rand3 = (float) (Math.random() * mult) + mult / 3;


        float AddAllRand = (rand1 + rand2 + rand3);
        float val1 = (100 * rand1) / AddAllRand;
        float val2 = (100 * rand3) / AddAllRand;
        float val3 = (100 * rand2) / AddAllRand;
        yVals1.add(new BarEntry(i, new float[]{val1, val2, val3}, null));
```