# how to use mpandroidchart to draw a barchart with intervals

Tags: mpandroidchart

[image]
The y-axis of the official case starts from 0

I hope to realize the image function through mpandroidchart

Comment: What have you done so far?

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this using a [stacked bar chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43540294/is-it-possible-to-create-a-multiple-color-stacked-bar-chart-using-mpandroidcha) and setting the color of the bottom bar to transparent.

For example:

```kotlin
// Make some fake data - the first array will be the offset,
// with a transparent color. The second is the height of the bar
val offset = listOf(42f, 55f, 55f, 80f, 55f, 110f)
val amount = listOf(50f, 50f, 50f, 50f, 50f, 55f)
val entries = offset.zip(amount).mapIndexed { i, oa ->
    BarEntry(i.toFloat(), listOf(oa.first, oa.second).toFloatArray())
}

// To make the bars different colors, make multiple BarDataSets
// instead of just one
val barDataSet = BarDataSet(entries,"data")
barDataSet.colors = listOf(Color.TRANSPARENT, Color.CYAN)
barDataSet.setDrawValues(false)

barChart.setTouchEnabled(false)
barChart.description.isEnabled = false
barChart.legend.isEnabled = false

val yAxis = barChart.axisLeft
yAxis.isEnabled = true
yAxis.axisMinimum = 40f
yAxis.axisMaximum = 160f
yAxis.granularity = 20f
yAxis.textSize = 24f
yAxis.setLabelCount(6, true)
yAxis.setDrawAxisLine(false)
yAxis.gridLineWidth = 1f
yAxis.setDrawGridLines(true)

barChart.axisRight.isEnabled = false
barChart.xAxis.isEnabled = false

barChart.data = BarData(barDataSet)
```

The result:

[image: floating bars]